# "Connection closed by remote host" in SSH, while in Putty all goes well

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

An interesting bug in SSH client (v.1.7) in Ubuntu 16.10. When I try to:

`ssh root@106.109.128.209`

I get:

```
Connection to 106.109.128.209 closed by remote host.
Connection to 106.109.128.209 closed.
```

When I do the same in Putty, all connects **well**.

What is the problem? I checked the obvious things in hosts.allow/hosts.deny, and sshd_config. I am pretty sure the problem is on client's side. Is the SSH client in Ubuntu 16.10 buggy?

In case it will be useful, here is the verbose outbut:

```
ssh -vvvv root@106.109.128.209
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "106.109.128.209" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 106.109.128.209 [106.109.128.209] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6 pat OpenSSH_6.5*,OpenSSH_6.6* compat 0x14000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 106.109.128.209:22 as 'root'
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: original KEX proposal: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: Compat: skipping algorithm "curve25519-sha256@libssh.org"
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: compat KEX proposal: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/volkova_ta/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 106.109.128.209
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:3gA2nZPHOKD98O1OE6D2+nZMJeyzv6iENPc3vVlEb0s
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/volkova_ta/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 106.109.128.209
debug1: Host '106.109.128.209' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: original KEX proposal: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: Compat: skipping algorithm "curve25519-sha256@libssh.org"
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: compat KEX proposal: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: key: /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55f42a6266d0), agent
debug2: key: /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug1: Authentication succeeded (none).
Authenticated to 106.109.128.209 ([106.109.128.209]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 5/6 cc -1)

Connection to 106.109.128.209 closed by remote host.
Connection to 106.109.128.209 closed.
Transferred: sent 1560, received 1944 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 17355740.7, received 21627923.0
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Output of `ls -l /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/` shows:

```
итого 36
-rw------- 1 volkova_ta volkova_ta 1679 июн 14 18:55 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 volkova_ta volkova_ta  407 июн 14 18:55 id_rsa.pub  
-rw-r--r-- 1 volkova_ta volkova_ta  222 июн 14 19:07 known_hosts
```

On host side:
Contents of `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` are empty.
MaxStartups is 10:30:100 (in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`)

Log from `journalctl _COMM=sshd`:

```
Jun 15 15:49:54 artik sshd[2623]: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Jun 15 15:49:54 artik sshd[2623]: Connection from 106.109.129.237 port 42774 on 106.109.128.209 port 22
Jun 15 15:49:54 artik sshd[2623]: Decryption integrity check failed [preauth]
```

Thank you!

UPD: I guess that that was because two machines have mismatching open-ssh versions. So they used different ciphers. `ssh -oCiphers=aes128-ctr root@106.109.128.209` solved the problem.

To setup the cipher forever: 
`sudo bash -c 'echo "Ciphers aes128-ctr" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config'`

Comment: Покажите вывод команды `ls -l /home/volkova_ta/.ssh/`.

Comment: @zombic Ready, see it in the post

Comment: Run `grep sshd /etc/hosts.allow`, `cat /etc/hosts.deny` and `grep MaxStartups /etc/ssh/sshd_config` on server.

Comment: And `tail -n100 /var/log/auth.log` on remote host after ssh connect.

Comment: Do you connect in Putty with an ssh-key or password?

Comment: @zombic I wrote the log in post. I do not have `/var/log/auth.log` (the logs are stored somewhere else) so I printed the iutput of `journalctl _COMM=sshd`.

Comment: @zombic I connect in Putty via password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Jun 15 15:49:54 artik sshd[2623]: Could not load host key:
>   /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

Try to generate the missing hostkey:

```
ssh-keygen -A
```

Comment: I did it, the error disppeared. But still, no connection, and  this error remains: `Jun 15 16:13:37 artik sshd[2615]: Decryption integrity check failed [preauth]`

Comment: Ah I found the solution. They have mismatching ciphers (I do not know for what reason). Easy to solve: `ssh -oCiphers=aes128-ctr root@106.109.128.209`. Thank you very much. You gave me the idea where to look for, and then I simply googled the error. Cheers!

Comment: Tatyana, could you add string in ssh config file `sudo bash -c 'echo "Ciphers aes128-ctr" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config'` and then try to connect without `-oCiphers=aes128-ctr`?

Comment: Sure, it works well! Thank you again!